# Static table view Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I've been working on trying to reproduce an animation lately, but despite all the tests and research i can't find a proper solution on how to deal with this kind of animation.

I've made a GIF of the animation I'm talking about (taken from "Captain Train" iOS app) : [Animation GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCJxT.gif)

Basically what it does is replace the tableView by various views, and also animates the navigation bar items very nicely.

**What I've done so far :**

I created a custom transition controller by creating a class like this one :

```
class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate  {

// MARK: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol methods
var openingFrame: CGRect?

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!
    if let containerView = transitionContext.containerView() {

        let animationDuration = self .transitionDuration(transitionContext)

        let snapshotView = toViewController.view.resizableSnapshotViewFromRect(toViewController.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true, withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero)
        snapshotView.frame = openingFrame!
        containerView.addSubview(snapshotView)

        toViewController.view.alpha = 0.0
        containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .TransitionNone,
            animations: { () -> Void in
                snapshotView.frame = fromViewController.view.frame
            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                snapshotView.removeFromSuperview()
                toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0

                transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
        })

    }
}

// return how many seconds the transiton animation will take
func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return 0.45
}

// MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol methods
func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return self
}

// return the animator used when dismissing from a viewcontroller
func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return self
}

}
```

That transition is working, I'm able to click on a table view item, and make an animated transition to another making my new view fit the cell's bounds, and then going full screen.

The function triggered when the user click on the cell looks like that :

```
    func presentDetailViewAnimated() {
        let transitionManager = TransitionManager()
        transitionManager.openingFrame = placeTableViewCell.frame

       let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("testAnimation")
    controller?.transitioningDelegate = transitionManager
       self.presentViewController(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)   
    }
```

This is fine, but it replaces the view. The animation I'm looking for takes place inside the tableView, and somehow replace the content, and that's where I'm lost.

I'm not super experienced with IOS animations so i don't know where to start to achieve such a result. I don't even know it this view really is a tableView or if they just fake it and everything is handled in a custom way.

I hope my post is clear enough, any comment / idea will be appreciated. :)

Comment: show the code for your animation. Without slowing it all down it's hard to see exactly what's happening, but I would start with getting the size of the tableviewCell clicked. Taking a snapshot of the destination controller and shrinking it to the frame of the cell and adding it to the transitionContext  containerView, then in your uiview animation block, expand it to full size. As i say, it's a quick glance approach.

Comment: @MDB983 I added the full class, but i don't think what i did was a good solution at all. I actually watched all the pictures when converting it as a GIF, and i could clearly see more animations than just a rectangle expanding. Like the table view cells being pushed away, and stuff like that. And i don't think it's another view, and i just realised it might very well be a container view, with transition animations like cross-dissolve.

Comment: Your snapshot view is your destination controller with alpha set to 0. All you see is the destinationView fading in. You need to get the frame of the TableViewCell. Apply the frame to your snapShotView, converted to the containerView coordinate system. This will  overlay a destinationViewController exactly over the tableViewCell. In your animation block, set the frame for the snapShotView, to the frame of the destinationViewControler. This will expand the snapshot to full size, starting from the tableViewCell, giving the impression that its  "Growing" from the tableViewCell.